# VBA Excel - How to Automatically Fill a date in multi-columns if i filled column A

Tags: vba, excel, date, multiple-columns

This is my first time to write a code and i try to write a code thats helps me to fill Columns **B**, **C** and **D** Automatically thats will happen when i fill Column **A** by myself.

this is the picture of that sheet i work on it now
[Worksheet Explaining what i Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RXJz.png)

[The final result must be like this Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlJ6z.png)

i try to google the code and i found a code but it not work at all

**This is the first code**

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
Set A = Range("A:A")
Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In Inte
        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
    Next r
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

also i try to write another code thats may helps me to fill Column **B** and **C** based on above code results but still not work.

**This is the code *written by me***

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change1(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Integer
For i = 6 To 1000
If Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" And Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" Then

   Cells(i, "C").Value = Date
   Cells(i, "C").NumberFormat = "mmm"
   Cells(i, "D").Value = Date
   Cells(i, "D").NumberFormat = "yyyy"

End If

Next

Range("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

anyone can help with that?

Comment: Never put values into the worksheet from a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro without turning off event handling first. Turn event handling back on before leaving the sub.

Comment: sorry i don't get it

Answer (score 2):

The [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro is triggered when one or more cells on the worksheet changes value. If you write values into the worksheet within the Worksheet_Change procedure (like you are with the dates) without first turning off event handling then another Worksheet_Change is triggered and the procedure tries to run on top of itself. Always turn off event handling with `Application.EnableEvents = False` before writing values to the worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:B")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim rw As Long, rng As Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Range("A:B"))
            If Application.CountA(Cells(rng.Row, "A").Resize(1, 2)) = 2 Then
                Cells(rng.Row, "C").Resize(1, 2).Value = Date
                Cells(rng.Row, "C").NumberFormat = "mmmm"
                Cells(rng.Row, "D").NumberFormat = "yyyy"
            End If
        Next rng
        Range("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Range("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    If CBool(Val(Err.Number)) Then _
        Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Remember to turn events back on with `Application.EnableEvents = True` before exiting the Worksheet_Change procedure or future value changes will not trigger the Worksheet_Change procedure again.

btw, the correct number format for *October* is *mmmm*, not *mmm*. The former gives the full month name; the latter only the three letter abbreviation (e.g. *Oct*).